# Mount ISO image on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mount, iso-image

You can easily open a `.dmg` is OS X thanks to their `drive utility` application. However, there is not a hint of this functionality in Windows 7.

What's the best program for mounting a `.iso` file in a virtual drive? 
*[Virtual CD-ROM Control Panel](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=38780)* (from Microsoft) seemed promising:

However, I could not install it. I moved the driver into `system32/drivers`, and when I browsed for it via the program, it wasn't in the `drivers` folder. I don't know why I thought it was promising. It's from Microsoft.

Now you see it:

[image: Now you see it]

Now you don't:

[image: Now you don't see it]

I promise you they're the same locations. I've made sure I can see all hidden files and folders and system files in the control panel.

Basically, if this Microsoft program is the best way to mount ISO image files in Windows 7? If so I'd like some guidance on how to install it. However, I doubt it is, I mean if its install is this flaky, nobody is using it.

What's the best third-party alternative?

Comment: The reason you don't see the drivers is because of folder redirection. For 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows, it redirects C:\Windows\system32 to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\

Comment: Unfortunately, questions seeking product or service recommendations are off topic on Super User; hence, as it stands this question is highly likely to be put on hold or closed as off topic. See [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5373/53590) on [meta] for some guidance on how to ask this type of question. You may alternatively consider asking on the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange; however, should you do so, please make sure to read [their guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/1813) before posting there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I really like [Virtual CloneDrive](https://www.elby.ch/en/products/vcd.html).

> Virtual CloneDrive works and behaves just like a physical CD/DVD drive, however it exists only virtually. Image files generated with CloneDVD or CloneCD can be mounted onto a virtual drive from your hard-disk or from a network drive and used in the same manner as inserting them into a normal CD/DVD drive.

Features:

- Supports all common image formats such as ISO, BIN, CCD
- Supports up to 8 virtual drives at the same time
- Easy to use - just double-click an image file to mount as a drive
- Virtual CloneDrive is freeware, you may use it at no cost.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger updated link